# scp with nohup in background wont work

Tags: scp, nohup

```
##!/bin/bash
FILE=$1;
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/scp -i /var/www/.ssh/XXX -P XXXXX "$FILE" user@ip.com:/dir1/dir2/ &
exit
```

this is my shellscript. This is called by php:

```
$sh = "/var/www/shdir/script.sh";
$param = '/path/to/file.mp4';
$exec  = $sh . ' "' . $param . '"';
shell_exec($exec);
```

this workes fine, but the files, i want to transfer, are too big to handle that in seconds, so i want to use nohup in the shellscript to run the scp-process in background. scp runs, but not in background. i dont know what why :/

thanks for helping!

Comment: Your PHP code is seriously insecure. I can help you fix the shell bits, but that doesn't make it less dangerous.

Comment: (...or, rather: that doesn't make the way you're invoking it from PHP less dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `nohup` here -- just detach directly all FDs from the TTY and use `disown`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1;
/usr/bin/scp -B \
  -i /var/www/.ssh/XXX \
  -P XXXXX \
  "$file" user@ip.com:/dir1/dir2/ \
  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

Note:

- the `-B` (batch) option to scp is enabled.
- stdin, stdout and stderr are all redirected to `/dev/null` (though you might do better to redirect the latter two to a log file while debugging)
- shebang starts with `#!`, not `##!`
- `disown` is used to remove the process from the shell's job table

---

The bigger problem is the use of `shell_exec()` with a concatenated string. The right way to launch a subprocess directly specifies each `argv` array entry. Unlike using a shell (as `shell_exec()` does), this prevents variables from executing arbitrary code (think about a file named `/uploads/evil-$(rm -rf $HOME)'$(rm -rf $HOME)'.mp4`; if you substitute that name into a string that's executed as code you're going to have a very bad day, even if you try to use quotes to protect it).